# JAX-RS CXF cross-parameters validation in case of sub-resources

Tags: java, rest, validation, jax-rs, cxf

I'm building REST services based on JAX-RS CXF and looking for a way how to validate pair of cross-parameters which depend from each other. The trickiest part is that I'm dealing with sub-resources and my method does not take all parameters to be validated at method level.

Let's take some simple entities as an example.

The top level API is CustomerResource:

```
POST /customer    -- add a new customer
GET  /customer/{customerId} -- get the customer by id
```

Sub-resource API is OrderResource:

```
POST /customer/{customerId}/order -- put a new order for the customer with {customerId}
```

where body is

```
{
    "itemId" : "123",
    "discountId" : "456"
}
```

**I need to validate that Customer with {customerId} has the discount {discountId} which belongs to him.**

```
@Path("/customer")
public interface CustomerResource {
    ...
    @Path("/{customerId}/order")
    OrderResource ordersOf(@PathParam("customerId") String customerId);
    ...
}

public interface OrderResource {
    ...
    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Order apply(@Valid OrderRequest orderRequest);
    ...
}

public class OrderRequest {
    private String itemId;
    private String discountId;
    ...
}
```

It's easy to validate each isolated parameter for @NotNull or for existence.
But my special discount validator should has **and customerId and discountId** at the time of validation to read right objects from DB and perform the check.

Of course I can do the validation later on service layer, but at the moment I am trying to keep service code nice and simple as possible.

Please also note, that it's too expensive to change API or update DB relations.